# scale canvas without redraw

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have a canvas with an image and some drawn lines. How can I scale and move all the canvas and not only the image? 
I use the drawImage method to scale now, but it only scales the image and not the drawn lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882154/resize-a-html-5-canvas-and-its-content-in-pure-javascript

Comment: Are you asking how to make the canvas element itself larger or how to keep the same sized canvas element but "zoom" in on the image+drawings? If "zooming", you will have to save the existing image+drawings to another canvas (or image) and then scale and finally redraw the image+drawings from the saved source.

Comment: @markE and for the resize, the same principle should apply except that he should redraw on a resized canvas. (The proposed dupe's answer do it with CSS which IMO is not the best way).

Comment: @Kaiido, Good point...the same principle applies when resizing the canvas element because doing so will auto-erase the canvas content (so the content must be saved somewhere and then redrawn). I too flinch at using CSS to resize the canvas. I flinch because scaling disproportionally will distort the content and because if additional lines are to be drawn those new line widths will have to be recalculated or else they will not match the original line widths. I would probably save the coordinates of the original lines and redraw them -- even though the question requests no redraws.